# Fragment Inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I need help regarding working on fragment inside fragment, actually I
am facing a problem on pressing back button. Application Main screen
has buttons and pressing on each button view replace with new
fragment(and that fragment contain inside another fragment),
dynamically adding/replacing fragment is working fine, by pressing
button1 fragment replaced, same happens when pressing button, but if
I press the button again, got an exception:

```
"Duplicate id 0x7f05000a, tag null, or parent id 0x7f050009 with
another fragment for com........ fragmentname"
```

means fragment or inner fragments are already added and I am trying
to add them again, anybody has idea how to work with fragment inside
fragment and moving back and forth without any problem, thanks for the
support.

MainActivity, where fragments are dynamical added and
replaced.

```java
public class FragmentInsideFragmentTestActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               onButtonClick(view);
            }
        });

        button2 =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onButtonClick(view);
            }
        });

        button3 =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
               onButtonClick(view);
            }
        });

        button4 =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               onButtonClick(view);
           }
        });
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        Fragment fg;

        switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button1:
                   fg=FirstFragment.newInstance();
                   replaceFragment(fg);
                   break;
           case R.id.button2:
                   fg=SecondFragment.newInstance();
                   replaceFragment(fg);
                   break;
           case R.id.button3:
                   fg=FirstFragment.newInstance();
                   replaceFragment(fg);
                   break;
           case R.id.button4:
                   fg=SecondFragment.newInstance();
                   replaceFragment(fg);
                   break;
        }
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
       FragmentTransaction trasection = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(!newFragment.isAdded()) {
            try {
                //FragmentTransaction trasection =
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trasection.replace(R.id.linearLayout2, newFragment);
                trasection.addToBackStack(null);
                trasection.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                // AppConstants.printLog(e.getMessage());
            } else {
                trasection.show(newFragment);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Layout: main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope I tried to clear my problem.

Comment: above code is working perfectly fine for me with android 3.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragments within Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847460/fragments-within-fragments)

Comment: for more details refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020531/1219456

Answer (score 305, accepted):

AFAIK, fragments cannot hold other fragments.

---

**UPDATE**

With current versions of the Android Support package -- or native fragments on API Level 17 and higher -- you can nest fragments, by means of `getChildFragmentManager()`. Note that this means that you need to use the Android Support package version of fragments on API Levels 11-16, because even though there is a native version of fragments on those devices, that version does not have `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: The platform really sucks here. I spent three hours debugging this because the inner fragment would render fine the first time, but would *disappear* after a screen orientation change. No exception, log info, nothing. Switching to `getChildFragmentManager()` and removing `setRetainInstance(true)` from the inner fragment (pity) fixed it. Thanks for saving my bacon again, @CommonsWare.

Answer (score 119):

[image]

I needed some more context, so I made an example to show how this is done. The most helpful thing I read while preparing was this:

- [Creating and Using Fragments](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)

## Activity

***activity_main.xml***

Add a `FrameLayout` to your activity to hold the parent fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

Load the parent fragment and implement the fragment listeners. (See [fragment communication](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).)

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ParentFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ChildFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Begin the transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.parent_fragment_container, new ParentFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void messageFromParentFragment(Uri uri) {
        Log.i("TAG", "received communication from parent fragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageFromChildFragment(Uri uri) {
        Log.i("TAG", "received communication from child fragment");
    }
}
```

## Parent Fragment

***fragment_parent.xml***

Add another `FrameLayout` container for the child fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_margin="20dp"
              android:background="#91d0c2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parent fragment"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***ParentFragment.java***

Use `getChildFragmentManager` in `onViewCreated` to set up the child fragment.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;    

public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Fragment childFragment = new ChildFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment_container, childFragment).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void messageFromParentFragment(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

## Child Fragment

***fragment_child.xml***

There is nothing special here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_margin="20dp"
              android:background="#f1ff91">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Child fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

***ChildFragment.java***

There is nothing too special here, either.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void messageFromChildFragment(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

## Notes

- The support library is being used so that [nested fragments](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) can be used before Android 4.2.

Comment: When I try to navigate to a different fragment from ParentFragment, it's fine, then I navigate back to ParentFragment and I get an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 73):

Since Android 4.2 (API 17) nested fragments become available http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

To place fragment inside other fragment use getChildFragmentManager()

It also available in support library!

Comment: Please update your answer to mention that support lib already supports nested fragements from android 1.6+

Answer (score 13):

Fragments can be added inside other fragments but then you will need to remove it from parent Fragment each time when `onDestroyView()` method of parent fragment is called. And again add it in Parent Fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

Just do like this :

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
                FragmentManager mFragmentMgr= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mTransaction = mFragmentMgr.beginTransaction();
                Fragment childFragment =mFragmentMgr.findFragmentByTag("qa_fragment")
        mTransaction.remove(childFragment);
        mTransaction.commit();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I had a fragment that inflated a view containing two children views. In `onActivityCreated()` it added two fragments, one into each of the views, using `getFragmentManager()`. This worked the first time, but on rotation and resume only one of the fragments was visible. Behavior was correct with `getChildFragmentManager()` instead. The approach suggested here threw an exception since the activity's `onSaveInstanceState()` had already been called. Committing the transaction using `commitAllowingStateLoss()` avoided the exception but did not solve the original problem.

Comment: any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052712/nested-fragment-backpress-child-inside-parent-have-problem

Answer (score 13):

you can use `getChildFragmentManager()` function.

example:

Parent fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_fragment, container,
            false);


    }

    //child fragment 
    FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
    ChildFragment fragB = new ChildFragment ();
    childFragTrans.add(R.id.FRAGMENT_PLACEHOLDER, fragB);
    childFragTrans.addToBackStack("B");
    childFragTrans.commit();        


    return rootView;
}
```

Parent layout (`parent_fragment.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FRAGMENT_PLACEHOLDER"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

Child Fragment:

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    View v ;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_fragment, container, false);


        v = rootView;


        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


    }


}
```

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem. You can use Support library and `ViewPager`. If you don't need swiping by gesture you can disable swiping. So here is some code to improve my solution:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
    final ArrayList<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    list.add(new TrFrag());
    list.add(new TrFrag());
    list.add(new TrFrag());

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return list.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

P.S.It is ugly code for test, but it improves that it is possible.

P.P.S **Inside fragment `ChildFragmentManager` should be passed to `ViewPagerAdapter`**

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing complicated. We cannot use `getFragmentManager()` here. For using Fragments **inside a Fragment**, we use `getChildFragmentManager()`. Rest will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use getChildFragmentManager(), follow the link :
[Nested Fragment](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `FrameLayout` to the fragment and replace it with another fragment when it initializes.

This way , you could consider the other fragment to be inside the first fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Curently in nested fragment, the nested one(s) are only supported if they are generated programmatically! So at this time no nested fragment layout are supported in xml layout scheme!

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for `MapFragment`, Android team says is working on it since Android 3.0. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347&utm_source=buffer&buffer_share=acc72) more information about the issue  But what you can do is by creating a Fragment that returns a `MapActivity`. [Here](https://github.com/inazaruk/examples/tree/master/MapFragmentExample) is a code example. Thanks to inazaruk:

**How it works:**

- MainFragmentActivity is the activity that extends `FragmentActivity` and hosts two MapFragments.
- MyMapActivity extends MapActivity and has `MapView.`
- `LocalActivityManagerFragment` hosts LocalActivityManager.
- MyMapFragment extends `LocalActivityManagerFragment` and with help of `TabHost` creates internal instance of MyMapActivity.

If you have any doubt please let me know

Answer (score 1):

That may help those who works on **Kotlin** you can use extension function 
so create a kotlin file let's say **"util.kt"** and add this piece of code

```
fun Fragment.addChildFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int) {

    val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(frameId, fragment).commit()
}
```

Let's say this is the class of the **child**

```
class InputFieldPresentation: Fragment()
{
    var views: View? = null
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        views = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.input_field_frag, container, false)
        return views
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can add the children to the **father fragment** like this

```
 FatherPresentation:Fragment()
{
  ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val fieldFragment= InputFieldPresentation()
        addChildFragment(fieldFragment,R.id.fragmet_field)
    }
...
}
```

where **R.id.fragmet_field** is the id of the layout which will contain the fragment.This lyout is inside the father fragment of course.
Here is an example

**father_fragment.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    ...

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/fragmet_field"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        </LinearLayout>
    ...

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved this problem by putting per Fragment into distinct layout.And I made just related Layout visible and made the others visibilities gone.

I mean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
           <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:id="@+id/button1"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Button1"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Button2"
                   android:id="@+id/button2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Button3"
                   android:id="@+id/button3"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
           <Button android:text="Button4"
                   android:id="@+id/button4"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="full_screen"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:id="action_For_Button1"
              android:visibility="visible">
                    <Fragment android:layout_width="full_screen"
                              android:layout_height="full_screen"
                              android:id="fragment1"
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
             / >
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="full_screen"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:id="action_For_Button1"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:visibility="gone">
                       <Fragment android:layout_width="full_screen"
                                 android:layout_height="full_screen"
                                 android:id="fragment2"
                                           .
                                           .
                                           .
             / >
        </LinearLayout>
                     .
                     .
                     .
        </LinearLayout>
```

I assumed that you will open your page as button 1 is clicked.You can control your fragment's visibilities on click action.You can make related Layout visible and the others gone and by Fragment Manager you can take your fragment.This approach worked for me.And since  ***view that has visibility:gone is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes I think this approach does not cause any space problem.***

P.S:I just tried to explain my solution code may have syntax mistakes or uncompleted structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a FragmentA in a MainActivity with STATIC Instances Method
2. Create fragment children: fragmentA1, fragmentA2 ... (FragmentA Has a layout contains Fragment Children)
3. Create a method set fragment in FragmentA
4. Use that Method for set fragment children FragmentA in fragmentA1, fragmentA2 ...
   This is that STATIC METHOD (in FragmentA):

   static OneFragment oneFragment;

   public static OneFragment Instances(){
   return oneFragment;
   }

   public View onCreateView(
   oneFragment = this;
   )

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

In an Activity you use `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()`. In the Activity's fragment use `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()`. In the XML files that will use `supportFragmentManager` and `childFragmentManager` you have to add a `FrameLayout`

Example:

*MainActivty* - will contain a FrameLayout which will house *HomeContainerFragment* via `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()`.

*HomeContainerFragment* - will contain a FrameLayout which will house *HomeFragment* via `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()`. You can also add views or whatever else in this XML and position the FrameLayout above/below them but for simplicity I just used a FrameLayout without anything else

*HomeFragment* - this will contain your views, buttons, etc

MainActivity XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

HomeContainerFragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/childFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

HomeFragment XML:

```
// views, buttons, etc
```

MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    addParentFragment()
}

fun addParentFragment() {

    val homeContainerFragment = HomeContainerFragment()

    try {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(binding.frameLayout.id, homeContainerFragment, "homeContainerId")
            .commit()
    } catch (exception: IllegalStateException) {
        println("something went wrong: ${exception.message}")
    }
}
```

HomeContainerFragment:

```
class HomeContainerFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        addChildFragment()
    }

    fun addChildFragment() {
    
        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    
        try {
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(binding.childFrameLayout.id, homeFragment, "homeId")
                .commit()
        } catch (exception: IllegalStateException) {
            println("something went wrong: ${exception.message}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Important:** This is just a general idea of how to add fragments. Please keep in mind that when your device rotates `onViewCreated` will get called again and then `addChildFragment()` will get called again. You need to use `savedInstanceState` to prepare for this situation.

Example:

```
class HomeContainerFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        addChildFragment(savedInstanceState)
    }

    val homeId = "homeId"
    
    fun addChildFragment(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        if (savedInstanceState == null && childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(homeId) == null {
    
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
            
            try {
                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(binding.childFrameLayout.id, homeFragment, homeId)
                    .commit()
            } catch (exception: IllegalStateException) { }
        }
    }
}
```