# How to compile DeskClock of android4.3 sourcecode

Tags: android

I download android 4.3 sourcecode from source.android.com,i find the app DeskClock and want to compile it,but I have a trouble...

in DeskClock.java
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
and
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
is it  different jar ?

this is the sourcecode:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.deskclock;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.deskclock.stopwatch.StopwatchFragment;
import com.android.deskclock.stopwatch.StopwatchService;
import com.android.deskclock.stopwatch.Stopwatches;
import com.android.deskclock.timer.TimerFragment;
import com.android.deskclock.timer.TimerObj;
import com.android.deskclock.timer.Timers;
import com.android.deskclock.worldclock.CitiesActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * DeskClock clock view for desk docks.
 */
public class DeskClock extends Activity implements LabelDialogFragment.TimerLabelDialogHandler {
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DeskClock";

    // Alarm action for midnight (so we can update the date display).
    private static final String KEY_SELECTED_TAB = "selected_tab";
    private static final String KEY_CLOCK_STATE = "clock_state";

    public static final String SELECT_TAB_INTENT_EXTRA = "deskclock.select.tab";

    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private Tab mTimerTab;
    private Tab mClockTab;
    private Tab mStopwatchTab;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public static final int TIMER_TAB_INDEX = 0;
    public static final int CLOCK_TAB_INDEX = 1;
    public static final int STOPWATCH_TAB_INDEX = 2;
    // Tabs indices are switched for right-to-left since there is no
    // native support for RTL in the ViewPager.
    public static final int RTL_TIMER_TAB_INDEX = 2;
    public static final int RTL_CLOCK_TAB_INDEX = 1;
    public static final int RTL_STOPWATCH_TAB_INDEX = 0;

    private int mSelectedTab;

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
        super.onNewIntent(newIntent);
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onNewIntent with intent: " + newIntent);

        // update our intent so that we can consult it to determine whether or
        // not the most recent launch was via a dock event
        setIntent(newIntent);

        // Timer receiver may ask to go to the timers fragment if a timer expired.
        int tab = newIntent.getIntExtra(SELECT_TAB_INTENT_EXTRA, -1);
        if (tab != -1) {
            if (mActionBar != null) {
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(tab);
            }
        }
    }

    private void initViews() {

        if (mTabsAdapter == null) {
            mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
            mViewPager.setId(R.id.desk_clock_pager);
            mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
            createTabs(mSelectedTab);
        }
        setContentView(mViewPager);
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(mSelectedTab);
    }

    private void createTabs(int selectedIndex) {
        mActionBar = getActionBar();

        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(0);
        if (mActionBar != null) {
            mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            mTimerTab = mActionBar.newTab();
            mTimerTab.setIcon(R.drawable.timer_tab);
            mTimerTab.setContentDescription(R.string.menu_timer);
            mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTimerTab, TimerFragment.class,TIMER_TAB_INDEX);

            mClockTab = mActionBar.newTab();
            mClockTab.setIcon(R.drawable.clock_tab);
            mClockTab.setContentDescription(R.string.menu_clock);
            mTabsAdapter.addTab(mClockTab, ClockFragment.class,CLOCK_TAB_INDEX);
            mStopwatchTab = mActionBar.newTab();
            mStopwatchTab.setIcon(R.drawable.stopwatch_tab);
            mStopwatchTab.setContentDescription(R.string.menu_stopwatch);
            mTabsAdapter.addTab(mStopwatchTab, StopwatchFragment.class,STOPWATCH_TAB_INDEX);
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(selectedIndex);
            mTabsAdapter.notifySelectedPage(selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        mSelectedTab = CLOCK_TAB_INDEX;
        if (icicle != null) {
            mSelectedTab = icicle.getInt(KEY_SELECTED_TAB, CLOCK_TAB_INDEX);
        }

        // Timer receiver may ask the app to go to the timer fragment if a timer expired
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null) {
            int tab = i.getIntExtra(SELECT_TAB_INTENT_EXTRA, -1);
            if (tab != -1) {
                mSelectedTab = tab;
            }
        }
        initViews();
        setHomeTimeZone();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent stopwatchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopwatchService.class);
        stopwatchIntent.setAction(Stopwatches.KILL_NOTIF);
        startService(stopwatchIntent);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Timers.NOTIF_APP_OPEN, true);
        editor.apply();
        Intent timerIntent = new Intent();
        timerIntent.setAction(Timers.NOTIF_IN_USE_CANCEL);
        sendBroadcast(timerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopwatchService.class);
        intent.setAction(Stopwatches.SHOW_NOTIF);
        startService(intent);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Timers.NOTIF_APP_OPEN, false);
        editor.apply();
        Utils.showInUseNotifications(this);

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY_SELECTED_TAB, mActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    public void clockButtonsOnClick(View v) {
        if (v == null)
            return;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.alarms_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AlarmClock.class));
                break;
            case R.id.cities_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, CitiesActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.menu_button:
                showMenu(v);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMenu(View v) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener () {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_item_settings:
                        startActivity(new Intent(DeskClock.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_item_help:
                        Intent i = item.getIntent();
                        if (i != null) {
                            try {
                                startActivity(i);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                // No activity found to match the intent - ignore
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_item_night_mode:
                        startActivity(new Intent(DeskClock.this, ScreensaverActivity.class));
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.desk_clock_menu);

        Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();
        MenuItem help = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_help);
        if (help != null) {
            Utils.prepareHelpMenuItem(this, help);
        }
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    /***
     * Insert the local time zone as the Home Time Zone if one is not set
     */
    private void setHomeTimeZone() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String homeTimeZone = prefs.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_HOME_TZ, "");
        if (!homeTimeZone.isEmpty()) {
        return;
        }
        homeTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(SettingsActivity.KEY_HOME_TZ, homeTimeZone);
        editor.apply();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Setting home time zone to " + homeTimeZone);
    }

    public void registerPageChangedListener(DeskClockFragment frag) {
        if (mTabsAdapter != null) {
            mTabsAdapter.registerPageChangedListener(frag);
        }
    }

    public void unregisterPageChangedListener(DeskClockFragment frag) {
        if (mTabsAdapter != null) {
            mTabsAdapter.unregisterPageChangedListener(frag);
        }
    }


    /***
     * Adapter for wrapping together the ActionBar's tab with the ViewPager
     */

    private class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        private static final String KEY_TAB_POSITION = "tab_position";

        final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, int position) {
                clss = _class;
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(KEY_TAB_POSITION, position);
            }

            public int getPosition() {
                return args.getInt(KEY_TAB_POSITION, 0);
            }
        }

        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList <TabInfo>();
        ActionBar mMainActionBar;
        Context mContext;
        ViewPager mPager;
        // Used for doing callbacks to fragments.
        HashSet<String> mFragmentTags = new HashSet<String>();

        public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mMainActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
            mPager = pager;
            mPager.setAdapter(this);
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(getRtlPosition(position));
            DeskClockFragment f = (DeskClockFragment) Fragment.instantiate(
                    mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, int position) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, position);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mMainActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mMainActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(getRtlPosition(position));
            notifyPageChanged(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            TabInfo info = (TabInfo)tab.getTag();
            mPager.setCurrentItem(getRtlPosition(info.getPosition()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            // Do nothing

        }

        public void notifySelectedPage(int page) {
            notifyPageChanged(page);
        }

        private void notifyPageChanged(int newPage) {
            for (String tag : mFragmentTags) {
                final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                DeskClockFragment f = (DeskClockFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
                if (f != null) {
                    f.onPageChanged(newPage);
                }
            }
        }

        public void registerPageChangedListener(DeskClockFragment frag) {
            String tag = frag.getTag();
            if (mFragmentTags.contains(tag)) {
                Log.wtf(LOG_TAG, "Trying to add an existing fragment " + tag);
            } else {
                mFragmentTags.add(frag.getTag());
            }
            // Since registering a listener by the fragment is done sometimes after the page
            // was already changed, make sure the fragment gets the current page
            frag.onPageChanged(mMainActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex());
        }

        public void unregisterPageChangedListener(DeskClockFragment frag) {
            mFragmentTags.remove(frag.getTag());
        }

        private boolean isRtl() {
            return TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault()) ==
                    View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
        }

        private int getRtlPosition(int position) {
             if (isRtl()) {
                 switch (position) {
                     case TIMER_TAB_INDEX:
                         return RTL_TIMER_TAB_INDEX;
                     case CLOCK_TAB_INDEX:
                         return RTL_CLOCK_TAB_INDEX;
                     case STOPWATCH_TAB_INDEX:
                         return RTL_STOPWATCH_TAB_INDEX;
                     default:
                         break;
                }
            }
            return position;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class OnTapListener implements OnTouchListener {
        private float mLastTouchX;
        private float mLastTouchY;
        private long mLastTouchTime;
        private final TextView mMakePressedTextView;
        private final int mPressedColor, mGrayColor;
        private final float MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED = 20;
        private final long MAX_TIME_ALLOWED = 500;

        public OnTapListener(Activity activity, TextView makePressedView) {
            mMakePressedTextView = makePressedView;
            mPressedColor = activity.getResources().getColor(Utils.getPressedColorId());
            mGrayColor = activity.getResources().getColor(Utils.getGrayColorId());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            switch (e.getAction()) {
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    mLastTouchTime = Utils.getTimeNow();
                    mLastTouchX = e.getX();
                    mLastTouchY = e.getY();
                    if (mMakePressedTextView != null) {
                        mMakePressedTextView.setTextColor(mPressedColor);
                    }
                    break;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    float xDiff = Math.abs(e.getX()-mLastTouchX);
                    float yDiff = Math.abs(e.getY()-mLastTouchY);
                    long timeDiff = (Utils.getTimeNow() - mLastTouchTime);
                    if (xDiff < MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED && yDiff < MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED
                            && timeDiff < MAX_TIME_ALLOWED) {
                        if (mMakePressedTextView != null) {
                            v = mMakePressedTextView;
                        }
                        processClick(v);
                        resetValues();
                        return true;
                    }
                    resetValues();
                    break;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                    xDiff = Math.abs(e.getX()-mLastTouchX);
                    yDiff = Math.abs(e.getY()-mLastTouchY);
                    if (xDiff >= MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED || yDiff >= MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED) {
                        resetValues();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    resetValues();
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void resetValues() {
            mLastTouchX = -1*MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED + 1;
            mLastTouchY = -1*MAX_MOVEMENT_ALLOWED + 1;
            mLastTouchTime = -1*MAX_TIME_ALLOWED + 1;
            if (mMakePressedTextView != null) {
                mMakePressedTextView.setTextColor(mGrayColor);
            }
        }

        protected abstract void processClick(View v);
    }

    /** Called by the LabelDialogFormat class after the dialog is finished. **/
    @Override
    public void onDialogLabelSet(TimerObj timer, String label, String tag) {
        Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (frag instanceof TimerFragment) {
            ((TimerFragment) frag).setLabel(timer, label);
        }
    }
}
```

i only have android.support.v4,where i can get the v13 ?
why it need import v4 and v13 at the same time ?

how can i pass the compile without modify code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the jar inside: `ANDROID_SDK_PATH/extras/android/support/v13`.

> These are exactly the same as the APIs added to the v4 support library, but rely on other platform components in Android 3.2. Use this library instead of v4 if you're developing for Android 3.2 and higher (all other APIs in the v4 library are already available with API level 13).

Source: [Support Library > Revisions > Android Support Library, revision 3 (July 2011)](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions).

The sentence is a bit old. The code needs both because things like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672688/842697

The v13's content: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/package-summary.html