# move to tabs with multiple fragments in each

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have today activities with multiple fragments for each activity. It's running nicely but I would like to move to a more modern tab interface. All the reading that I do is showing to me that it is not easy at all implementing multiple fragments per tab.

Have I no choice: could I keep activities and link them to tabs or is not supported at all?

If the answer is yes, could I leverage cool feature lke swipe tabs?

if the answer is no, could you recommend readings before I start breaking everything :)
Most of my activities are using 2 fragments because I use the classical list in one pane and the action to a click item in another pane.

thanks!

Comment: I've not personally tried it but it sounds like nested fragments on each tab would do the trick: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments. This functionality is also in the support library, so it's good on older Android versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

With API 17 and up you can do some work with nested fragments that could allow you to use all of the fragment tools like swipe features. Take a look at the post from CommonsWare and Nik [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment)