# How to add fragments in TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with blow layout that called `Menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"/>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout"/>

</TableLayout>
```

1. I added it into my `MainActivity`
2. That `Menu` fragment adds another `Menu` fragment into its `TableLayout`:

   ```
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.tableLayout, new Menu()).commit()
   ```
3. Now the second `Menu` want to add some fragments into itself `TableLayout`

   ```
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.tableLayout, new MyFragment()).commit()
   ```

But that fragment adds in the first `Menu`.

---

**How can I add a fragment into the second `Menu` fragment?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Gordak [Fragment Inside Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment)

get your `FragmentManager` by using `getChildFragmentManager()` not by `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`