# ViewPager shows empty content

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a calculator with two fragments for simple and scientific calculators. But the Viewpager is empty though scrollable between two fragments no content of the fragments is visible.
Also, if I change IsViewFromObject to true,Both the fragments are visible on top of each other.

Here is the viewpager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.root.calculatorui.Science">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:gravity="right|bottom"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp" />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_below="@id/txtResult"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the fragmentActivity code used to initialize the ViewPager:

```
package com.example.root.calculatorui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class Science extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_for_calculator);
        ViewPager viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d("Load", "Started Science");
                    return new ScienceFragment();
                case 1:
                    Log.d("Load", "Back to Simple");
                    return new SimpleFragment();
                default:
                    return new SimpleFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the simpleFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.root.calculatorui.Science">

    <Button
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtResult"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear" />

    <Button
        android:text="←"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonClear" />

    <Button
        android:text="÷"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonDel"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonDel" />

    <Button
        android:text="x"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMul"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonDiv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtResult" />

    <Button
        android:text="7"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="8"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonDel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:text="9"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonDiv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
        android:id="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSub"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonDiv" />

    <Button
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:text="6"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn5" />

    <Button
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSub"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn2" />

    <Button
        android:text="%"
        android:id="@+id/btnPercentage"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPercentage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnPercentage" />

    <Button
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnDot"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn0" />

    <Button
        android:text="="
        style="@style/Button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn6" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is SimpleFragment.Java

```
package com.example.root.calculatorui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by root on 14/1/17.
 */

public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    public SimpleFragment(){}

    public Fragment newInstance(int s, String title) {
        SimpleFragment sfrag=new SimpleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", s);
        args.putString("someTitle",title);
        sfrag.setArguments(args);
        return sfrag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating `Fragment`s inside `Fragment` ? Is that necessary? Shouldn't it be in the `MainActivity`?

Comment: The google example for this used a Fragment Activity, So, I did the same

Comment: Could you paste the link of that example? Also: **fragments cannot hold other fragments.** http://stackoverflow.com/a/6672688/4409113

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Its the same output even if i extend from AppCompatActivity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is MainActivity Class.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return ScienceFragment.newInstance(0, "Science");
                case 1: return SimpleFragment.newInstance(1, "Simple");
                default: return ScienceFragment.newInstance(0, "Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}

This is ScienceFragment
/**
 * Created by Techno Blogger on 15/1/17.
 */

public class ScienceFragment extends Fragment {
    private String title;
    private int page;

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static ScienceFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        ScienceFragment fragmentFirst = new ScienceFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_science, container, false);
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textScience);
        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is SimpleFragment

```
public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static SimpleFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        SimpleFragment fragmentFirst = new SimpleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple, null);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just uploaded the same to my Github Account, try downloading it, and then run. 
Please let me know if it helps...
https://github.com/Shekhar14o3/ViewPagerWithFragment

Comment: Your github is working but i wonder whats the problem with my code?

Comment: Just try Cleaning the Project, or Restart Studio with Invalidating Cache. Also chek your Manifest and gradle file with mine Code.

Comment: In which method do i add the calculator functionailty inside the fragment?

Comment: In SimpleFragment, there you need to give the reference of all the Buttons, and then perform all the operations in that Class. 
By the way, what you want to d in your Project, means what is the flow.

Comment: A simple calculator that perform basic as well as scientific operations and look similar to the default google calculator

Comment: Ok, then for that why you need two Fragments, you can do that only in a SimpleFragment itself.

Comment: How come? I thought i did need two fragments to provide enough space like google calci slides sideways to show a scientific operations

Comment: You can use the landscape mode, or put all the Button in a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: seriously? `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` Did you see my answer?

Comment: But its sliding the fragments @Mohsen

Answer (score 0):

You're not making an instance of the fragments in the `getItem(int position)` method.

Change it as per the following and it should work:-

```
 @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Log.d("Load", "Started Science");
                        return new ScienceFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");

                    case 1:
                        Log.d("Load", "Back to Simple");
                        return new SimpleFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 2");

                    default:
                        return new SimpleFragment.newInstance("DdefaultFragment, Instance default");
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no such method as newInstance()

Comment: The fragments overlap each other in the Science Activity

Comment: put break statement after every case.

Comment: No such symbol as newInstance

Comment: Since each it has return statement there isnt a need for a break

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentPagerAdapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}}
```

And setup viewpager like this

```
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ScienceFragment(), "Science");
    adapter.addFragment(new SimpleFragment(), "Simple");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: The science fragment is visible but the simple one isnt

Comment: Try to replace getSupportFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Inside ScienceFragment
`public static ScienceFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    ScienceFragment fragmentFirst = new ScienceFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}` 
In MainActivity.
`
                case 0: return ScienceFragment.newInstance(0, "Instance 1");
                case 1: return SimpleFragment.newInstance(1, "Instance 2");
                default: return ScienceFragment.newInstance(0, "Default");
      
    }`

Comment: getChildFragmentManager: No such symbol

Comment: Also add java of your fragment

Comment: You have assigned an id in you fragment's relative layout as activity_main .. And trying to use that to inflate the layout for your fragment.. There is a difference between layout and id.. When you're using R.layout then you will have to use exact name of your xml layout like your xml name is fragment_simple.xml then you will use R.layout.fragment_simple

Comment: My layout name is activity_main too

Answer (score 0):

Use this in ScienceFragment,

```
public static ScienceFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    ScienceFragment fragmentFirst = new ScienceFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}
```

Similarly in SimpleFragment, and use this in MainActivity.

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return ScienceFragment.newInstance(0, "Instance 1");
                case 1: return SimpleFragment.newInstance(1, "Instance 2");
                default: return ScienceFragment.newInstance(0, "Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bismeet Singh, try to use this piece of Code. It works.

Comment: It shows the science fragment but not the simple one

Comment: can you show me the layout of each Fragment. I'm sure the issue is there, as mine is working fine.  For testing give different background to each layout of your Background. And make sure that you are using the newInstance method in SimpleFragment also.

Comment: added the simple fragment

Comment: In your xml, the width and height are missing, try adding this two line in your every Button.

  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: They are using a styles.xml

Comment: Which contains the necessary attributes

Comment: Let me send you the complete Classes which I'm using.

Comment: I added the Complete Class, let me know if it helps.