# Child fragment disappears when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, fragment, android-nested-fragment

**UPDATE 1:**

Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest file solved the problem for portrait mode. But in landscape mode the problem still exists.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Current structure is like this: **Activity -> Fragment -> Child Fragment**

I did it as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467807

I have an EditText in the child fragment, when it gets focused, the keyboard pops up and the content in child fragment is disappearing. When the keyboard gets dismissed, contents of child fragment comes back.
Also I noticed, the contents of child fragment is disappearing when orientation is landscape.

This is the layout structure:
[image: Layout breakdown]

This is how it shows before keyboard pops up:
[image: Before keyboard]

And when the keyboard pops up:
[image: Keyboard pops up]

TextView in the parent fragment is always shown, only the contents of child fragment is gone. What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: try `android:windowSoftInputMode=AdjustPan`. By default the softkeyboard try to move the content when it opens.

Comment: @UmarHussain that solved one problem. Now its all fine in portrait mode. But in landscape mode child fragments content is gone