# How to combine activity layout with fragment

Tags: android

I need to use part of my activity layout in fragmnent, but I dont know how.
If I use overlaying FrameLayout, I will not have access to the elements behind it. And duplicate part of activity_main_layout in several fragments also is not good idea.

[image: 1]

Comment: Probably you should start reading this first: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: you will have reference of activity in fragment you could interact with activity ui from that refrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like i need to use fragments with transparent container in the middle

Answer (score 0):

A fragment can't host an activity. Instead you can use nested fragments for this purpose. [Fragment Inside Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment/39467807#39467807)

Comment: but if I'll use nested fragment , i'll lose data after parent fragments switching.
To be more concrete: 
It will be something like paint with papercut in the middle. And switching of fragments should change only yellow part(tools buttons), but shouldn't change papercut