# Android - connecting bottom navigation with tabView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to create an app where I use a bottom navigation bar and a tabView for each selected bottom option. I‘m not sure how to set it up properly, I thought about opening activities for each option of the bottom Navigation and working with fragments for the tabs. Is it recommendable to do it that way, or are there better ways to handle it? Is it possible to use fragments for the bottom bar and use even more fragments for the tabView?

Comment: It's not recommended to use activities with `BottomNavigationView`, you can use as many fragments as you like, even fragments inside fragments.

Comment: here is an example @LieForBananas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment

Comment: @Eminem I don't understand, why did you tag me? :)

Comment: @LieForBananas couse you still lie,for bananas,stop it

Comment: @Eminem I will never stop lying for them :) But you can have nested fragments :)

Comment: Thanks to you :) can you tell me what‘s the advantage of nested fragments?