# Viewpageindicator inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, actionbarsherlock

With a SherlockActionBar i've created a nice interface. In landscape mode you see both listfragment and "detailsfragment".

Now I would like to a add a viewpageindicator (https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) inside the detailsframe, so i would look like this:

```
--------------------------|
|_1___|TAB1 | TAB2 | ETC  |
|_2___|-------------------|
|_3___|Example: content   |
|_4___| TAB1 of listitem 1| 
|_5___|___________________|
```

I hope this is clear. So basicly I would a FragmentManager/TabPageIndicator inside a fragment.

I this possible? I can't figure it out.. :(

Thank you!

Comment: So you have a ListViewFragment on the Left?
Then each ListView Item will load a different RHS Fragment which contains: TabPageIndicator and ViewPager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not put a `Fragment` inside a `Fragment`. You can however put a `ViewPager` inside a fragment and get the result you're looking for.

I was facing the same issue a while ago for one of my apps (only I wanted the `ViewPager` to contain some `ListView`s). This was the end result (see the lines; red contains `Fragment`, blue `ViewPagerIndicator`, green `ViewPager`):

[image: Example ViewPager inside a Fragment]

I accomplished this with the following steps. Fist, for the detail-fragment, I created the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerIndicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, I set up a custom PagerAdapter to populate the ViewPager and the TabPageIndicator:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

    // constructor
    ...        

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // remove the object (we don't want to keep it in memory as it will get recreated and cached when needed)

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        viewPager.removeView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View pager, final int position) {
        // inflate your 'content'-views here (in my case I added a listview here)
        // similar to a listadapter's `getView()`-method

        View wrapper = ... // inflate your layout
        ... // fill your data to the appropriate views

        ((ViewPager) pager).addView(wrapper);
    }

    public String getTitle(int position) {
        ... // return the title of the tab
    }
}
```

Next, in my fragment, I set the following:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private TabPageIndicator mIndicator;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        View detailsFrame = context.findViewById(R.id.details_fragment);
        // setup your adapter: pass data, etc.
        this.pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(...);
        this.viewPager = (ViewPager) context.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        this.mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) context.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerIndicator);
        this.mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello please provide the full code.. i am unable to understand at some point thanks in advance

Comment: @Reinier , what is this View detailsFrame = context.findViewById(R.id.details_fragment); what does it represent ? In which layout is that i.d put?

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest fragments inside fragments. It will be displayed fine, but it will crash when you will want to replace some of them using transactions.

Have a look a these:

- [Problem putting a fragment into another fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321831/problem-putting-a-fragment-into-another-fragment)
- [Android: Can you nest Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments)