# ViewPagerIndicator inside a Fragment: NullPointer with Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9700554/1335004) to use a ViewPager with indicator inside a fragment, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7SJ2.jpg). (Just a mock up).
There's navigation spinner that changes the fragment. Each "page" would contain a ListView.

So basically I'm looking for:
SherlockFragmentActivity -> SherlockFragment -> ViewPager -> ListView

However, when I try and implement what I saw in the answer I get an error with findViewById();
I assume it's because I'm not getting the correct "context".

Here's my Fragment:

```
public class HomeViewFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private HomePagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private TitlePageIndicator mIndicator;
    private Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext();            

        mAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(context);

        mPager = (ViewPager)context.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)context.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Delete `context = getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext();`

Step #2: Replace `context.findViewById` with `getActivity().findViewById`

Step #3: Replace all remaining occurrences of `context` with `getActivity()`

Step #4: Delete your `onActivityCreated()` implementation, as it is not doing anything

Step #5: Resolve that you will never again use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know **specifically why you need it in a given circumstance**

Comment: findViewById isn't a method in a fragment though, what should I do there?

And my adapter needs a context passed to it, not a fragment.

Comment: @osxoep: Sorry, I wasn't paying close enough attention. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that builds my code but now I've got another error. I know what I'm doing tonight now :)