# ViewPager as part of a Fragment in a Multipane Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Hi developer i want to build a custom layout for tablets in landscape mode.
I will display a two pane layout with one fragment left and one fragment right.
The left fragment is a viewPager with 3 other listfragment. The right fragment shows details about the selected row of the left listView from one page of the viewPager.
I didn't find a good solution for this problem. I read you can't put fragments into fragment but how can i build my viewPager as part of a fragment?

Has anybody a good solution or tutorial for this problem?
I found this one but it is not so clear for me: [Viewpageindicator inside fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699881/viewpageindicator-inside-fragment)