# Parent Fragment Not Displaying Child ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am using the Android Compatibility Package with API Level 10. I have a FragmentActivity and in its onCreate method, I dynamically add a newly created Fragment instance (myPagerFragment) using:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, myPagerFragment).commit();
```

The myPagerFragment contains a ViewPager which makes use of a FragmentPagerAdapter. The implementation is according to the Android documentation with nothing special. When a button in one of the ViewPager child Fragments is clicked, then the myPagerFragment will be removed and replaced by a new Fragment instance (myOtherFragment) using:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myOtherFragment).commit();
```

The myOtherFragment displays a simple view containing a button. When this button is clicked, then the myOtherFragment will be removed and replaced again with a new instance of myPagerFragment using:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myPagerFragment).commit();
```

At this point the myPagerFragment no longer displays as it did in the beginning, but instead, displays a blank screen. There is no crash and nothing useful in the log.

I have tried this method with other views, for instance, replacing myPagerFragment with a Fragment that contains a simple view definition, and this works correctly and as expected. It is only Fragments that contain a ViewPager, that displays incorrectly at successive loads.

How can I make Fragments that contain a ViewPager to always display correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest fragments in fragments. Hence, you cannot put a `FragmentPagerAdapter` in a `ViewPager` in a `Fragment`. Please redesign your UI to resolve this conflict, such as by getting rid of the outer-most `Fragment`.

Comment: Note that nested `Fragment`s are now **available**, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments)