# Two ListFragment inside one Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have created following thing in android using android  compatibility support package

[image]

Basically i have a FragmentAcitivity which shows two Tabs. One Tab represents `Fragment #1` and second is `Fragment #2`. Fragment #2 has two ListFragment i.e. ListFragment #1 and ListFragment #2 , but the problem is m i am getting following error when i try to do that.

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
     at com.myexample.template.TextVoiceFragment.onCreateView(TextVoiceFragment.java:19)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:837)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1041)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:616)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1359)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:422)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:86)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:453)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(ViewPager.java:563)
     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:6015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1124)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1129)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1129)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1129)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1129)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1129)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:731)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
     at com.myexample.template.VoiceTemplate.onActivityCreated(VoiceTemplate.java:82)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:858)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1020)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1099)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:263)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
```

***Binary XML***

```
<fragment class="com.myexample.template.VoiceTemplate" 
    android:id="@+id/voiceListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
/>
```

***Line number 19 contains*** inside onCreateView of TextVoiceFragment.class which is Fragment #2 in this case

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_voice_fragment, container, false);
```

***Line number 82 contains*** in code inside onActivityCreated of VoiceTemplate.class which extents ListFragment & a ListFragment #2

```
// 
getListView().setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

 });
```

i have tried replacing Fragment #2 with FragmentActivity as follows

[image]

but in that case i am getting following error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myexample.template.TextVoiceFragment
```

here TextVoiceFragment is Tab second

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. Here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840128/android-fragments-2-fragment-1-frame-layout Can you please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is creating your problem, but in the future you might have others because nested fragments are not supported.

You can read this answer of a Android Framework Engineer about that: [Android: Can you nest Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments)

Comment: so better to stick with simple activity stuff rather then using fragments ?

Comment: Fragments are useful. You just have to be careful not to have fragments inside fragments.

Comment: Hmm okay , but what should i do in this case :) , where i want two listview in side a fragment :)

Comment: You have ListFragments#1 and #2. You should have ListView#1 and #2

Comment: But is it possible to create ListView instead of ListFragment inside a Fragment ?

Comment: Not really sure. Never used that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an Activity that holds two ListFragments.  This is basically what you see in the GMail application.  If you want Fragment #1 to appear beside both ListFragment #1 and ListFragment #2, you'll have to have all 3 as siblings in the same Layout or FragmentManager.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. Here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840128/android-fragments-2-fragment-1-frame-layout Can you please point me in right direction?