# How to create 2 Fragment inside Fragment of each Nav Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-actionbar

I follow  [Action bar tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) in Android Dev site

In `onCreate` of `ActionBarActivity.class` I add tab like this;

```
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.artist)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                    this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

so, I will have `ArtistFragment extend Fragment` but I'm not sure how to add 2 fragment(ListFragment and DetailFragment) inside `ArtistFragment` What would be inside `ArtistFragment.class`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support fragment in fragments (for now). You should try to make a layout that supports 2 fragments that communicate with your activity instead OR 1 fragment which handles the work that both fragments would do.

Comment: @Shruti http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Answer (score 2):

What Warpzit said.  Per [Android: Can you nest Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6221763/517561), Fragments cannot be nested.  Your Fragment can cause another Fragment to be instantiated alongside it by reaching up to its parent Activity.  I wouldn't ordinarily recommend this, as Fragments should be a unit of encapsulation.  But if your Fragments are tightly coupled (for example, a detail display corresponding to a list item), I could see doing it.

Your code would look something like this:

```
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            MyFragmentClass myFragment = new MyFragmentClass();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, myFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the FragmentTabs example from the API Demos project to be very useful.

Just create a new Android sample project from Eclipse and choose the API demos (try API 13). Also for the support (compatibility) library, there's a FragmentTabs demo in the Support4Demos