# ViewPager within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is it possible to have a ViewPager (which pages between fragments) within another fragment?

To answer my own question some have found "hacky" solutions with a degree of success: [Display fragment viewpager within a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700226/display-fragment-viewpager-within-a-fragment), and there have been semi "official" answers that [fragments within fragments are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847770/768584). Both of these questions were asked a year or so ago, so I was hoping support for fragments within fragments may have progressed somewhat. Is this the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ViewPager extends ViewGroup`, so yes you can.

and you can embed `Fragments` into `Fragment`

Comment: You can but it's not simple, see my post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments/9700314#9700314