# Imbeding a fragment in either a Dialog or FragmentDialog

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I am trying to embed a Fragment in either a Dialog or DialogFragment

```
public class addAccountDialog extends DialogFragment 
{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_account_dialog, container);
    accountType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
            {
            passwordFragment newFragment = new passwordFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_base, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }

}



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_base"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" > 
        </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried this using with both a Dialog and DialogFragmentto no avail. Has anyone been able to implement a fragment inside a dialog.

thank you in advance.

Roger

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  I don't believe it is possible, as the fragment manager is from the activity class.  Maybe if we knew what you are trying to accomplish, we could offer other suggestions.

Comment: You CAN nest Fragments, but it's not advisable:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments

Answer (score 1):

You aren't able to put `Fragments` within other `Fragments`.

My suggestion would be to put your `Fragments` within an `Activity` like normal and then give the `Activity` a `Dialog` theme by doing this in the XML:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

edit: just a note, as of API-17 (4.2) you can now nest Fragments: [Nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Comment: Thank you Atlos for your timely response and the code, I will try the Theme.Dialog and see how it works and, if it provides the experience that I am looking for.