# PagerView of fragments inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an issue. First of all I have a menu where when you select an option it creates a fragment that can be slid in and out.

When the activity is first created it populates my view with Frag#1. 
Frag#1 contains a PagerView, that contains a variable number of fragments.
When Frag#1 is auto created from the activity being started, the PagerView is populated perfectly.

However if I then switch to any other Frag by calling .Replace, and then come back to Frag#1 calling .replace, the PagerView populates invisibly.

However Even though the fragments inside the PagerView are invisible I am able to swipe though them, and access the TextViews, Layouts, and ImageViews inside them. So they exist otherwise I would get null for the Views, or no such ID exists. But the fragments in the PagerView stay missing from sight.

When I reach the end of the PagerView, it populates the last one and I can see the fragment inside it. Now when I scroll back to the first one I can see it too now. However the one in the middle is still gone, but I can access the views in it.

Does anyone have an Idea what is going on here?

If instead of trying to replace the old fragment with Frag#1 I restart the activity it works fine again.

i.e.

```
public void reload() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You wrote: `Frag#1 contains a PagerView, that contains a variable number of fragments`. Are you nesting fragments inside each other? That only works if your using Android 4.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments

Comment: A fragment that is contained in a framelayout, hold a ViewPager. This ViewPager has a pageradapter that contains Fragments. So in a sense yes there are fragments inside a view of a fragment. However, it works. It works when the activity is first created. It does not work after after destroying the Fragment containing the ViewPager, and then remaking it a second time. (although it half works, as described above)